# VSCode no encuentra la ruta del SDK .NET en Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: .net, ubuntu, vscode, sdk

¡Hola!

Necesito ayuda con un problema del VSCode. Empecé un curso para aprender C#, pero como uso Ubuntu tuve que acceder a la guía oficial de Microsoft para instalar los SDK's y el .NET Core. Al parecer, todo se instaló correctamente, pero al abrir el VSCode, con la extensión para C#, me sale siempre un error de que no encuentra la ruta del SDK.
Intenté seguir varias guías, pero la mayoría están en inglés y, como soy novato en Linux, tampoco dan una ayuda guiada para principiantes.

Instalación del SDK:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
dotnet-sdk-6.0 ya está en su versión más reciente (6.0.400-1).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 13 no 
actualizados.
```

Luego, al usar el comando dotnet en la terminal de Linux, me sale lo siguiente:

```
dotnet --info

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

Sin embargo, si voy a la ruta donde está instalado .NET, tengo una carpeta sdk, que contiene una carpeta con la versión 6.0.4, y dentro tiene ficheros. ¿No se supone que es esta la ruta del SDK?

Desde ya, ¡gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Agrega la información referida a la instalación, porque tal cual está la pregunta, no hay SDK instalado. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Añadí la información de la instalación del SDK.

Comment: ¿Has cerrado la terminal y la has vuelto a abrir? Puede que suene poco convincente, en algunos casos, esto hace un refresh para algunos comandos.

Comment: Si, varias veces lo he hecho, y de igual manera con el VSCode; y hasta he reiniciado la PC.  Aún así, me sigue sin detectar el SDK tanto en la terminal como en el VSCode.